# Regex to find specific words inside string

Tags: php, regex

Well, I'been searching and testing but I don't know how to do the following:

I have this text:

```
*Intro*
| [C] – [G] – [Am] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]

*VERSE 1*
=[C][G][Am]
=cu{a}nto he esp{e}rado este mo{m}ento
| [F] – [F] – [Dm] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]
```

And I need to find all the words inside [], but only from the line starting with "|"

I know that using:

```
^\|.*
```

Will find the lines from start to end, and that using:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Will select all the bracket and its content but I don't know how to say

**Find this `^\|.*` and to the result, apply this `\[(.*?)\]`**

Why not step by step? because I would like to use **preg_replace** to wrap the word with HTML tags.

Am I even taking the right approach?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are the html tags all the same? (like `<span>` and `</span>`)  Please show your desired end result including tags.

Comment: This is the result I'm looking for `<span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">C</span>`

Comment: and you want to remove the pipes and square brackets?  Please edit your question to show EXACTLY the output you want based on the input you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with plain text, you may use the following regex on it:

```
'~(?:\G(?!\A)|^\|)[^][\r\n]*\K\[(.*?)]~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/50GzFA/3)

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^\|)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`, `\G` matches both start of a string and the end of the previous match, so the first position should be subtracted using a negative lookahead `(?!\A)` - *not at the start of the string*) or (`|`) start of a line (`^`) followed with a literal `|` (`^\|`)
- `[^][\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]`, CR and LF (to stay on the same line)
- `\K` - match reset operator omitting the text matched so far
- `\[` - a `[`
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first
- `]` - a literal `]`.

Another approach is to use a `preg_replace_callback` with a regex that matches all lines starting with `|` and, inside a callback function, replace all the `[...]` substrings.

```
preg_replace_callback('~^\|.+~m', function ($m) {
        return preg_replace('~\[(.*?)]~', '<span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">'.$m[1]."</span>", $m[0]);
    }, $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/YxeHkz):

```
$s = <<<TXT
*Intro*
| [C] – [G] – [Am] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]

*VERSE 1*
=[C][G][Am]
=cu{a}nto he esp{e}rado este mo{m}ento
| [F] – [F] – [Dm] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]
TXT;

echo preg_replace_callback('~^\|.+~m', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\[(.*?)]~', '<span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">$1</span>', $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

Output:

```
*Intro*
| <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">C</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">G</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">Am</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">G</span>

*VERSE 1*
=[C][G][Am]
=cu{a}nto he esp{e}rado este mo{m}ento
| <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="" title="">G</span>
```

Comment: How was I supposed to get to that regex? This worked like I needed it, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are targeting substrings between square brackets that follow `|` or `–`, so this is what my pattern does (with an optional trailing space):

Pattern: `/([|–] )\[([^]]+)\]( ?)/`

Replacement: `$1<span class="chord" data-original-title="$2" title="$2">$2</span>$3`

[Pattern/Replacement Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zBz7fy/2/)

PHP Implementation: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36d3c3944bd0704be8cb439435d19c18b0061260))

```
$txt='*Intro*
| [C] – [G] – [Am] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]

*VERSE 1*
=[C][G][Am]
=cu{a}nto he esp{e}rado este mo{m}ento
| [F] – [F] – [Dm] – [F] – [Dm] – [G]';
echo preg_replace('/([|–] )\[([^]]+)\]( ?)/','$1<span class="chord" data-original-title="$2" title="$2">$2</span>$3',$txt);
```

Output:

```
*Intro*
| <span class="chord" data-original-title="C" title="C">C</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="G" title="G">G</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="Am" title="Am">Am</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="F" title="F">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="Dm" title="Dm">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="G" title="G">G</span>

*VERSE 1*
=[C][G][Am]
=cu{a}nto he esp{e}rado este mo{m}ento
| <span class="chord" data-original-title="F" title="F">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="F" title="F">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="Dm" title="Dm">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="F" title="F">F</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="Dm" title="Dm">Dm</span> – <span class="chord" data-original-title="G" title="G">G</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using backtracking control verbs to skip lines that start with a character that isn't `|`:

```
preg_match_all('~^[^|\v].*\R*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[\K[^]]+~m', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/2qNejs/1)